# Mongoose how to populate and match populated field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, filter

I have a CheckoutSchema that referencies an Checkin object that have the property email which I want to match.
I would like to know how can I do that.

```
//CheckinModel file:
const CheckinSchema = new Schema({
    eventId: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, { 
    timestamps: true,
});


//CheckoutModel file:
const CheckoutSchema = new Schema({
    checkin: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Checkin',
        required: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

Comment: Can you specify your schemas. That would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I just edited it right now to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Checkin.find({ email: your_email })
       .populate(checkoutSchema)
       .exec()
       .then(result => {
            })
       .catch(error => {
            })
```

Try pass email address that you want to match as your_email. This `result` receive when it success and `error` receive when error happens.